# Stop VB from showing xml comment preview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

When you create an XML comment in C# and collapse it you only see:

```
<Summary>...
```

But in VB you could potentially see

```
Initializes the fubble to the watzer. This is actually the second line.
```

Having that line over your code can introduce lots of unwanted noise when trying to debug a class. Is there any way to turn off xml comment previews for VB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unchecking the `Generate XML documentation file` on the Compile tab for the VB.NET project should do it.

Remember to turn this back on again when you are finished if you want to have your XML comments built. However leaving this off will improve Visual Studio performance.

Comment: Cheers buddy, just to other people looking to do this. Don't forget to turn it back on otherwise your comments wont compile into the class.

Comment: @deanvmc - If you accept this then other people will be able to find this as a solution.

Comment: I had to wait for a bit (Which is a silly restriction on stack overflow if you ask me.)

Answer (score -1):

How about this: My VS 'Compile' tab does not have 'Generate XML documentation' checkbox or wherever. My comments suddenly stop being compiled/output just few weeks ago. Though this is true for few projects only. All new projects have no problem adding and saving comments, HOWEVER...

I think all this kind of "minor" and "major" problems come from the approach that MS took in recent years where some 'Options' are controlled by another 'Options' to turn the 1st option On and Off having another, 3rd 'Option', ON while changing the 1st 'Option'; oh ya, don't forget: make sure credentials are given in proper way and format, having 1st and 3rd options OFF. Complicated? Let as make a decision for you based on your (IDE) usage experience!...
...
...Or something similar